# Resolving a relative url path to its absolute path

Tags: python, url, path

Is there a library in python that works like this?

```
>>> resolvePath("http://www.asite.com/folder/currentpage.html", "anotherpage.html")
'http://www.asite.com/folder/anotherpage.html'
>>> resolvePath("http://www.asite.com/folder/currentpage.html", "folder2/anotherpage.html")
'http://www.asite.com/folder/folder2/anotherpage.html'
>>> resolvePath("http://www.asite.com/folder/currentpage.html", "/folder3/anotherpage.html")
'http://www.asite.com/folder3/anotherpage.html'
>>> resolvePath("http://www.asite.com/folder/currentpage.html", "../finalpage.html")
'http://www.asite.com/finalpage.html'
```

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Yes, there is [`urlparse.urljoin`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urljoin), or [`urllib.parse.urljoin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urljoin) for Python 3.

```
>>> try: from urlparse import urljoin # Python2
... except ImportError: from urllib.parse import urljoin # Python3
...
>>> urljoin("http://www.asite.com/folder/currentpage.html", "anotherpage.html")
'http://www.asite.com/folder/anotherpage.html'
>>> urljoin("http://www.asite.com/folder/currentpage.html", "folder2/anotherpage.html")
'http://www.asite.com/folder/folder2/anotherpage.html'
>>> urljoin("http://www.asite.com/folder/currentpage.html", "/folder3/anotherpage.html")
'http://www.asite.com/folder3/anotherpage.html'
>>> urljoin("http://www.asite.com/folder/currentpage.html", "../finalpage.html")
'http://www.asite.com/finalpage.html'
```

for copy-and-paste:

```
try:
    from urlparse import urljoin  # Python2
except ImportError:
    from urllib.parse import urljoin  # Python3
```

Comment: For a RFC 3986 and unicode compliant replacement, see [uritools](http://pythonhosted.org/uritools/).

Comment: This doesn't work if the second component is absolute, sadly. For example, `urljoin("http://example.com/blah.html", "./././whoa.html")` *does* remove the dots, while `urljoin("http://example.com/blah.html", "/./././whoa.html")` doesn't.

Comment: Note that this is limited to a hard-coded set of schemes. If you're using a custom/unpopular scheme, you'll need to modify `urllib.parse.uses_relative` and `urllib.parse.uses_netloc` to include your scheme if you want this to work. Not too pretty wrt global state, but I don't see any other way to do this without patching the standard lib.

Comment: @obskyr This does work. It behaves the same as the [algorithm as defined by RFC 1808 section 4](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1808#section-4).  Therefore it works "correctly".  Collapsing `.` sections for relative paths and not absolute paths is a curiosity of RFC1808 but it is the standard way to interpret such URLs.

Answer (score 15):

You can also call the `urljoin` function through Python's `requests` library.

This code:

```
import requests

requests.compat.urljoin('http://example.com/foo.html', 'bar.html')
```

Will return a value of `http://example.com/bar.html`