# Convert relative URL to fully qualified URL using Python

Tags: python, string, http, url

I'm looking for a way to fully qualify a URL using Python.  I have my current page URL, such as:

http://www.foo.com/Stuff/Mike/Doc.html

and I have my href, such as:

href="../Bob/Doc.html"

What I need to build is:

http://www.foo.com/Stuff/Bob/Doc.html

Does Python have any libraries that can parse paths like this?  I looked around the docs for urllib and urllib2, but couldn't find anything like that.  Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resolving a relative url path to its absolute path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476511/resolving-a-relative-url-path-to-its-absolute-path)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [`urlparse`](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html) library.

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> urlparse.urljoin("http://www.foo.com/Stuff/Mike/Doc.html","../Bob/Doc.html")
'http://www.foo.com/Stuff/Bob/Doc.html'
```

Comment: Nice!  I knew this would turn out to be ridiculously easy in Python.

Answer (score 3):

For additional:

If you are using python 3, The library name has changed:

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urljoin
>>> urlparse.urljoin("http://www.foo.com/Stuff/Mike/Doc.html","../Bob/Doc.html")
'http://www.foo.com/Stuff/Bob/Doc.html'
```