# Python requests, xpath download whole link

Tags: python, xpath, python-requests

I am trying to scrape this page
http://kenyalaw.org:8181/exist/kenyalex/actview.xql?actid=CAP.%2016

And have this sample python code:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

r = requests.get("http://kenyalaw.org:8181/exist/kenyalex/actview.xql?actid=CAP.%2016")
data = html.fromstring(r.content)
print(data.xpath("//div[@class='subleg']/a/@href")[0])
```

and this gives me this output:

sublegview.xql?subleg=CAP. 16

but when I use mouse hover on this xpath, there is different link, as you can see on the picture below:

http://kenyalaw.org:8181/exist/kenyalex/sublegview.xql?subleg=CAP.%2016

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think its just denotes the branch of the current URL that you are scraping i guess, so remove everything after the last `/` in your URL using Regex and join the href of the targeted element (i think it makes sense to you)

```py
import requests
import re
from lxml import html

url = "http://kenyalaw.org:8181/exist/kenyalex/actview.xql?actid=CAP.%2016"
r = requests.get(url)
data = html.fromstring(r.content)
print(''.join([re.sub(r'(?<=/)[^/]*$', '', url), data.xpath("//div[@class='subleg']/a/@href")[0]]).replace(' ', ''))
```

Tell me if its not working...

Comment: You can even use `urljoin` to join, which is simpler and more flexible than your (quite neat) regex (https://stackoverflow.com/a/476521/1581658)

Comment: actaully, this is ok answer, now I figured out that it opens different link, this link http://kenyalaw.org:8181/exist/kenyalex/sublegview.xql?subleg=CAP.%2016

Comment: @CiricAleksandar its just a space in between the url, you can just do the `str.replace(' ', '')` method to solve it tho

Comment: @CiricAleksandar ok so are there anymore errors?

Comment: there are not errors, but now I realise that i need this link http://kenyalaw.org:8181/exist/kenyalex/sublegview.xql?subleg=CAP.%2016, but I can just replace words and get this link

Comment: thats it, you can also do that too, so no more errors right?