# how to edit a link that is stored in a list

Tags: python, list, url, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
import re


def getHTMLdocument(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    return response.text


url_to_scrape = 'https://www.parliament.gov.sg/about-us/structure/the-cabinet'
links = []

while True:

    html_document = getHTMLdocument(url_to_scrape)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_document, 'lxml')

    if soup.find_all('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("/details/")}) == []:
        break

    for link in soup.find_all('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("/details/")}):
        if link.get('href') not in links:
            links.append(link.get('href'))
            print(links)
```

Currently, this is the code that I have, which gives me an output list of

['/mps/current-list-of-mps/mp/details/lee-hsien-loong', 'https://www.parliament.gov.sg/mps/list-of-current-mps/mp/details/heng-swee-keat', 'https://www.parliament.gov.sg/mps/list-of-current-mps/mp/details/teo-chee-hean', 'https://www.parliament.gov.sg/mps/list-of-current-mps/mp/details/tharman-shanmugaratnam', 'https://www.parliament.gov.sg/mps/list-of-current-mps/mp/details/ng-eng-hen', 'https://www.parliament.gov.sg/mps/list-of-current-mps/mp/details/vivian-balakrishnan', 'https://www.parliament.gov.sg/mps/list-of-current-mps/mp/details/k-shanmugam', 'https://www.parliament.gov.sg/mps/list-of-current-mps/mp/details/gan-kim-yong', 'https://www.parliament.gov.sg/mps/list-of-current-mps/mp/details/s-iswaran', 'https://www.parliament.gov.sg/mps/list-of-current-mps/mp/details/grace-fu-hai-yien', 'https://www.parliament.gov.sg/mps/list-of-current-mps/mp/details/chan-chun-sing', 'https://www.parliament.gov.sg/mps/list-of-current-mps/mp/details/lawrence-wong', 'https://www.parliament.gov.sg/mps/list-of-current-mps/mp/details/masagos-zulkifli-bin-masagos-mohamad', 'https://www.parliament.gov.sg/mps/list-of-current-mps/mp/details/ong-ye-kung', 'https://www.parliament.gov.sg/mps/list-of-current-mps/mp/details/desmond-lee', 'https://www.parliament.gov.sg/mps/list-of-current-mps/mp/details/josephine-teo', 'https://www.parliament.gov.sg/mps/list-of-current-mps/mp/details/indranee-rajah', 'https://www.parliament.gov.sg/mps/list-of-current-mps/mp/details/mohamad-maliki-bin-osman', 'https://www.parliament.gov.sg/mps/list-of-current-mps/mp/details/edwin-tong-chun-fai', 'https://www.parliament.gov.sg/mps/list-of-current-mps/mp/details/tan-see-leng']

With the next part of my code, I am trying to scrape data from each of these links, however, as the first link within the list doesn't come out as a valid url, I am not able to obtain information from it.

How can I edit it such that it will be the same as the other urls in the list?

many thanks

Comment: You don't want to simply "edit a link that is stored in a list". That could just be done with `lst[0] = lst[0].upper()`, for example. You want to resolve a _relative link_ to its _absolute path_, so you should _ask that question instead!_ Does this answer your question? [Resolving a relative url path to its absolute path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476511/resolving-a-relative-url-path-to-its-absolute-path)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you add the string to the list you can check if he has the right format by using this code and correct it if needed:

```
def correct_url(url):

    if not url.startswith('https://www.parliament.gov.sg'):
        url = f'https://www.parliament.gov.sg{url}'
    return URL
```

the for loop adopted to the new function:

```
for link in soup.find_all('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("/details/")}):
        if link.get('href') not in links:
            links.append(correct_url(link.get('href')))
            print(links)
```

Comment: This doesn't work for relative urls that do not contain a leading backslash

Comment: @gerdadiegandalfziege Please don't ask others to change their votes. Voting is personal choice and everyone should be free to rate content according to their judgement. Don't take votes personally. They only represent someone's opinion of the content and not the user who posted it.